# How to format the string to certain length and show it new line in an array using PHP

Tags: php, string, string-length

i have an array like this,

```html
 Array
        (
            [0] => 1    CS pizza                      Rs. 400

            [1] => 1    Pepperoni Pizza               Rs. 300

            [2] => 1    Creamy Tomato Soup            Rs. 100

            [3] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore
Noodles     Rs. 200

            [4] => 1    Mix Triple Noodles            Rs. 210

            [5] => 1    Veg Triple Schezwan
Noodles     Rs. 180

            [6] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore
Noodles     Rs. 200

            [7] => 1    New POS Item                  Rs. 100

        )
```

i want to format the data to like this using php ,

```html
 Array
        (
            [0] => 1    CS pizza                      Rs. 400

            [1] => 1    Pepperoni Pizza               Rs. 300

            [2] => 1    Creamy Tomato Soup            Rs. 100

            [3] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore
                        Noodles                       Rs. 200

            [4] => 1    Mix Triple Noodles            Rs. 210

            [5] => 1    Veg Triple Schezwan
                        Noodles                       Rs. 180

            [6] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore
                        Noodles                       Rs. 200

            [7] => 1    New POS Item                  Rs. 100

        )
```

i am using this code to do it like this , but i am unable to this,

```html
$value['quantity']."    ".wordwrap(str_pad($value['itemname'],25), 25,"\n")."     "."Rs. ".$value['basePrice']."\n"
```

How to proceed , can anyone help on this.

Comment: but css is better option

Comment: You do _not_ want to do this using an array holding plain text, since this is a layouting question. You need some layout language to achieve what you are trying to do. `HTML` is a good layout language, actually. You want to give it a try.

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh css cannot really change the way an array dump is rendered...

Comment: well .. nobody wants to deal with php array itself which you have printed above. Instead we can get values in html and can always update the layout using some css or something appropriate. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: css always a option for formatting but in this scenarion, doing it by php only is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

ok here i got my answer,

```html
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($order_data['results']['itemDet'] as $key => $value) {
    $first25 = substr($value['itemname'], 0, 20);
    $theRest = substr($value['itemname'], 20);
    if(strlen($value['itemname']) < 20 ){
        $final_thrd_array[$cnt] = $value['quantity']."    ".str_pad($first25,25)."     "."Rs. ".$value['basePrice']."\n";
    }else{
        $final_thrd[0] = $value['quantity']."    ".str_pad($first25,25)."     "."Rs. ".$value['basePrice']."\n";
        $final_thrd[1] = "  "."    ".str_pad($theRest,25)."     "."\n";
        $final_thrd_array[$cnt] = $final_thrd[0];
        $final_thrd_array[++$cnt] = $final_thrd[1];
    }
    $cnt ++;
 }                                  
using this code i can able to form my format,
                                      
Array
    (
        [0] => 1    CS pizza                      Rs. 400

        [1] => 1    Pepperoni Pizza               Rs. 300

        [2] => 1    Creamy Tomato Soup            Rs. 100

        [3] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore          Rs. 200

        [4] =>        Noodles                      

        [5] => 1    Mix Triple Noodles            Rs. 210

        [6] => 1    Veg Triple Schezwan           Rs. 180

        [7] =>       Noodles                       

        [8] => 1    Veg Triple Singapore          Rs. 200

        [9] =>        Noodles                      

        [10] => 1    New POS Item                  Rs. 100

    )
```